# Is there a way to trigger a Jenkins build after publishing an npm package to Sonatype Nexus?

Tags: jenkins, build, npm, nexus, post-commit-hook

Is there a way to trigger a Jenkins build after publishing an npm package to Sonatype Nexus?

I've been clicking through Sonetype's docs for Nexus and exploring my Nexus admin console. I've also tried searching for some plugins but I'm not sure if I'm not using the right terminology or if there just isn't a lot of info about calling a URL or something after publishing a package to Nexus.

Comment: Have you found any solution for your problem - I would like to do the exact same configuration you described in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it but it looks like you're hunting for this?

https://github.com/vbehar/nexus-webhook-plugin

You'd have to create a middleware to consume the hook and trigger a build via the jenkins api.

Comment: Looks like this isn't compatible with the latest version: https://github.com/vbehar/nexus-webhook-plugin/issues/1

Comment: Now you can use integrated webhooks: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/webhooks